# query specific chunk file using python

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo, gridfs

I'm doing a project using mongodb and python. In my project have files to store, but that file are greater than 16MB. For that I used gridfs to solve my inserting issue. Now I have a requirement to query specific chunk file, without retrieving whole file. It bit of challenge to me and can you guys guide me to solve this issue.